# Unable to remove unneeded platforms from console

Tags: chatbase

In the chatbase UI, when I try to filter by a specific platform, there are a large number of platforms that don't mean anything to me. There is no way I can find to remove/clean up these platforms.

Tried reaching out to chatbase support, but they are unresponsive.

Not sure it's a coding problem

again, it's not a coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Chatbase. I was able to look into your message data and noticed that we are receiving random code snippets in the platform